# AVAudioPlayer successfully calls play method but not playing sound

Tags: ios, xcode

AVAudioPlayer successfully calls play method and is working properly in the simulator but it is not playing sound. The device has iOS 7.1.1. This is the code that I have used.

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
         NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"miata-hn" ofType:@"wav"];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSError *error = nil;
        /* Start the audio player */
        self.playerAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error];
        self.playerAudio.volume = 1;

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error localized description %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }

        if (self.playerAudio != nil)
        {
            /* Set the delegate and start playing */
            self.playerAudio.delegate = self;

            if ([self.playerAudio prepareToPlay] && [self.playerAudio play])
            {
                NSLog(@"player success");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"sound player failed to play audio");
            }
        }
        else
        {
                /* Failed to instantiate AVAudioPlayer */
        }
```

Comment: you have seen `player success` log ?

Comment: Yes it logs player success log

Comment: Do you try play other file? If other files have sound, should be a problem of file.

Comment: Yes i have tried this for other file of same type "wav" as well as for other type like mp3 and m4v. But it was not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got The solution. After adding this line of code the audio is audible in app.
AVAudioSession should be activated.

**

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
```